# Erro na saída da função optim ao criar uma estrutura de regressão

Tags: r

Ao rodar a simulação abaixo obtenho o erro no final do código, alguém pode me ajudar a resolve-lo?

```
#Valores iniciais dos parâmetros usados para gerar t
#Ou seja, Valor verdadeiro dos parâmetros
beta0=2
beta1=1
alpha0=3
alpha1=1
truevalue=c(beta0,beta1,alpha0,alpha1)
#Tamanho das amostras
n=100
#Vetor de parâmetros
beta=matrix(c(beta0,beta1),nrow=2,ncol=1)
alpha=matrix(c(alpha0,alpha1),nrow=2,ncol=1)
#Vetor de 1's
const1 <- rep(1,n);
const <- cbind(const1);
#Vetor de cováriavel com distribuição unif(0,1)
X1=matrix(runif(n, 0, 1),nrow=n,ncol=1)
Z1=matrix(runif(n, 0, 1),nrow=n,ncol=1)
#Matrizes de covariáveis
X <-matrix(c(const,X1),nrow=n,ncol=ncol(X1)+1)
Z <-matrix(c(const,Z1),nrow=n,ncol=ncol(Z1)+1)
#Número de colunas de X e Z
p=ncol(X)
q=ncol(Z)
#Vetor de médias
mu=exp(X%*%beta)
#Vetor de dispersão
phi=exp(Z%*%alpha)

#Gerando uma variável aleatória t com distribuição Birnbaum-Saunders(mu,phi)
remove(beta,beta0,beta1,alpha,alpha0,alpha1)

z<-cbind(rnorm(n,0,1))
t<-((phi*mu)/(phi+1))*((z/sqrt(2*phi))+(sqrt((z/sqrt(2*phi))^2+1)))^2

Loglik<-function(theta,dados){
  p=ncol(X)
  q=ncol(Z)
  beta=theta[1:p]
  alpha=theta[p+1:p+q]
  mu=exp(X%*%beta)
  phi=exp(Z%*%alpha)
  lv=sum((phi/2)-(3/2)*log(t)+(1/2)*log(phi+1)-log(4*sqrt(pi*mu))+log(t+(phi*mu/(phi+1)))-(phi/4)*((t*(phi+1)/(phi*mu))+(phi*mu/(t*(phi+1)))))
  #lv=sum(log(((exp(phi/2)*sqrt(phi+1))/(4*sqrt(pi*mu)*t^(3/2)))*(t+((phi*mu)/(phi+1)))*exp((-phi/4)*((t*(phi+1)/(phi*mu))+(phi*mu/(t*(phi+1)))))))
  return(-lv)
}
#Chute inicial para as funções de estimação
start=cbind(1,2,2,3)
#Estimation with function optim
bs_op=optim(start,Loglik,method="BFGS",dados=t,hessian = T) 
bs_op$par
```

> Error in optim(start, Loglik, method = "BFGS", dados = t, hessian = T) : 
>     initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

Comment: Dá uma olhada neste aqui e vê se te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383746/mle-error-in-r-initial-value-in-vmmin-is-not-finite

Comment: Oi @EduardoAlmeida acredito que os erros são por motivos distintos, no meu caso as definições de alpha, beta, t e os demais acredito estarem corretos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que a sugestão do Eduardo nos comentários tem a ver com o seu problema, sim. [Nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32445478/724200) para aquela pergunta, foi dado a dica para se verificar o resultado da sua função com os valores iniciais. No seu caso:

```
> Loglik(start, t)
[1] NA
```

Isso indica que algo está errado na sua função. Investigando-a linha a linha, podemos observar um problema aqui:

```
> alpha=theta[p+1:p+q]
> alpha
[1] NA NA
```

Os `NA`s aparecem porque a conta `p+1:p+q` resulta no vetor `(5, 6)`, sendo que `theta` só possui 4 elementos. Pensando um pouco, meu palpite é que você tenha errado na prioridade do operador `:`, e por isso obteve esse resultado. Imagino que você queria os valores `c(3, 4)`, e neste caso deveria alterar o código para:

```
alpha <- theta[(p+1):(p+q)]
```

Veja que agora o resultado não é de `NA`s:

```
> alpha
[1] 2 3
```

E a função `optim` roda perfeitamente:

```
> bs_op <- optim(start,Loglik,method="BFGS",dados=t,hessian = T)
> bs_op$par
        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 1.00167 2.078868 1.655399 3.696152
```

Deixo pra você a avaliação deste resultado, pois você sabe melhor o que esperar de tanta matemática. :)

A "lição" aqui é (considerando que este era o problema), frente a um erro, testar seu código linha a linha e observar o resultado de cada passo, frequentemente você achará a fonte de erro assim.

Comment: Prezado @Molx, mais uma vez muito obrigado por sua ajuda, já tinha cometido este mesmo erro em outra simulação a um tempo e não me recordei! Concordo com sua sugestão e agradeço muito!